# Arrange nplot() by y-axis values

Tags: rcharts

I am using a [multiBarHorizontalChart](http://grangermoch.com/LNI/rateVariance.html) with nplot() to show variance from a mean rate. I have "negative change" bars highlighted in red and positive rate change bars in green– via grouping by a "posneg" variable. When I group by this variable however, the years on the y axis are no longer ordered. Any idea how I could maintain the order of the years while still grouping by this variable? Personally, I think the color difference makes the graph a lot easier to interpret. Here's a reproducible example, using the data hosted on Socrata:

```
install.packages("RSocrata")
library(RSocrata)

url="https://opendata.socrata.com/dataset/Preliminary-Data-Data-Visulaization-Project-8-12-1/4xgc-ygke"

dfRatePer100= read.socrata(url)

dfRatePer100=subset(dfRatePer100, select=c(1,3), Year!="NA")

colnames(dfRatePer100)= c("Year", "Dollar.Rate")

dfRatePer100$Dollar.Rate= as.numeric(dfRatePer100$Dollar.Rate, 3)
dfRatePer100$mean= mean(dfRatePer100$Dollar.Rate)

dfRatePer100=dfRatePer100%>%
  mutate(rateVariance= Dollar.Rate - mean) %>%
  arrange(desc(Year))

dfRatePer100$PosNeg=ifelse(dfRatePer100$rateVariance>0, "Positive rate change from mean", ifelse(dfRatePer100$rateVariance<0, "Negative rate change from mean", "No change from mean"))

ratePer100 <- nPlot(rateVariance~ Year, group="PosNeg",data =     dfRatePer100,type = 'multiBarHorizontalChart')
ratePer100$chart(showLegend=T)
ratePer100$chart(showControls=F)
ratePer100$chart(color = c('green','red'))
ratePer100$yAxis(axisLabel='Variance from mean rate (in dollars)')
ratePer100$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format('.2f')(d)} !#")
ratePer100$set(width=600)
ratePer100
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but a suggestion, since looking at the source code, `nvd3` `multiBarHorizontalChart` will group by the groups first and sort then by values, so don't think possible.  [`taucharts`](http://github.com/hrbrmstr/taucharts) might be a good option if `rCharts` is not a requirement.

```
library(rCharts)

df <- data.frame(
  year = as.character(2000:2012)
  ,value = runif(13,-1,1)
)
df$group <- ifelse(df$value>0,"positive","negative")

np <-nPlot(
  value ~ year,
  group = "group",
  data = df,
  type = 'multiBarHorizontalChart'
)
np$chart(color = c('green','red'))
np

library(taucharts)
tauchart( df ) %>%
  tau_bar( "value", "year", "group", horizontal=TRUE) %>%
  tau_legend()
```

Comment: Thanks a ton timelyportfolio! Rcharts isn't a requirement, I just need to be able to save the graph as an html file within my script (similar to nvd3's df$save()) and not by manually clicking "export to html" in R Studio. Do you know if this is possible? .

Comment: `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` should export nicely

Comment: Perfect. Any way to control the size of the plot outputted? Thanks a ton.

Comment: there is also as.iframe coming in https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/pull/154.  For now you can install that branch with `devtools::install_github("ramnathv/htmlwidgets@feature/iframe").  this is what I use for my building widgets posts.